# Libstdc++ incompatibility on Qt crosscompiling from Debian amd64 to armhf

Tags: c++, arm, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

I would like to cross-compile my app on a debian testing amd64 to an armhf debian testing system. I can compile it, but when I try to run it on the target machine I get an error: 
 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found

On the target machine the maximum of

strings /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC

output is: GLIBCXX_3.4.20

My compiler is g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf 5.3.1. 
the maximum of 
strings /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libstdc++.so.6

is GLIBCXX_3.4.21

Maybe that is the reason of incompatibility. I try to find an earlier version of gnueabihf, but I cannot find anything in the debian repository.

both machine has debian testing op. system.

How can I solve this incompatibility?

Comment: What is a typical compile command, and what is the link command? More to the point, did you use `--sysroot=...`? Also, Debian and Ubuntu cross-compilers seem to be completely broken at the moment due to path problems. I filed a few bug reports against Ubuntu because of them.

Comment: Yes it used the sysroot, but it doesn't care about the libstdc++ version, because it use dynamic linking. I found the -static-libstdc++ flag for linker. That is the solving for this problem.  
thx
Zamek